# Changing the margin on an Angular MDC Button Icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

Since updating to Angular MDC icons, I can no longer work out how to control the position of the icon, relative to the button text, using css classes. For example, when applying a margin via CSS to an icon in a button, the margin is overridden by the MDC style.

In the example below, the test class applied to the accented (pink) button is overridden by the MDC icon styles. When applied inline, on the primary (purple) coloured button, the margin is applied as intended.

Is there a way to use css classes in this instance, other than using ng-deep, or must I resort to inline styles?

[Icon margin not applied when in component CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es5HB.png)

[Inspector screenshot of order of precedence for accented (pink) button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDfU1.png)

The below code is available at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/orw1e6?file=src%2Fexample%2Fbutton-overview-example.css).

Component TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

/**
 * @title Basic buttons
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'button-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-overview-example.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatDividerModule, MatIconModule],
})
export class ButtonOverviewExample {}
```

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Flat</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary"><mat-icon style="margin-right:30px;">home</mat-icon>Applied in style</button>
    <button mat-flat-button color="accent"><mat-icon class="test">home</mat-icon>Applied in CSS</button>
    <button mat-flat-button color="warn"><mat-icon>home</mat-icon>No Style</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
  display: table;
}

.example-label {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.example-button-row {
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.example-button-row .mat-mdc-button-base {
  margin: 8px 8px 8px 0;
}

.example-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.example-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 120px;
}

.test {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```